# Run Java Jar within Python Google Cloud Function

Tags: java, python, ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to port over some old Ruby code I used to run on Heroku to a Python-based Google Cloud Function.

This code runs Apple's Reporter tool which is "a command-line tool that you can use to download your Sales and Trends reports and Payments and Financial Reports". Docs can be found [here](https://help.apple.com/itc/contentreporterguide/en.lproj/static.html).

The **Ruby** code worked well for years until yesterday, running on Heroku with a Ruby + Java build pack. A small snippet of this, where options are args received :

```
options = [
    vendor_id,
    file_type,
    sub_file_type,
    'Daily',
    trimmed_date,
    version
]
Dir.chdir("#{Rails.root}/tmp/") do
  stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("java -jar #{Rails.root}/public/jars/Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Robot.XML Sales.getReport #{options.join(', ')}")
  return {:status => status, :error => stderr.to_s, :stdout => stdout.to_s }
end
```

The error I'm seeing on Heroku after no code or stack updates is `Network is available but cannot connect to application. Check your proxy and firewall settings and try again.`

Most of our other similar processes have been moved to Google Cloud Functions, so after getting nowhere with the above error I thought I'd move this also.

So a similar snippet this time in **Python**:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def execute_reporter_jar(vendor_id, trimmed_date, file_type, api_version):
    process = Popen(["java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.getReportVersion Sales, Detailed"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    out, err = process.communicate()
    print("returncode = %s", process.returncode)
    print("stdout = %s", out)
    print("stderr = %s", err)
```

This works well locally, but when I deploy to Gooogle Cloud it seemingly runs successfully in a few ms, however, nothing actually happens and when I dig deeper it seems the subprocess is returning a `127 - command not found` error. So it seems the cloud function can't access Java.

After a good 24hrs, I've hit a wall with this. Can anyone help? I have zero Java knowledge and I know cloud functions have a Java runtime, but I would prefer to stick with Python.

The ultimate aim is for Apple's reporter to run and save the requested file to Google Cloud Storage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The execution environment for Cloud Function's with Python runtime (both 3.7 and 3.8) is currently based in Ubuntu 18.04 (check the information [in this link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#runtimes)).

The runtime only includes the following [system packages](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/python-system-packages#included_packages) and running subprocess is usually not a recommended idea as the system packages included are limited.

If it's paramount for you to stick with Python you could try to deploy your function using the [BuildPack CLI](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building/pack) and [extending the builder image](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks#extending-the-builder-image) to install Java on the Python runtime or if your application can be dockerized consider building an image yourself with Java included and [deploying your application in Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python).

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I'll check out the links you've given, but I was beginning to come to the same conclusion about a dockerized image deployed to cloud run. Python isn't paramount, but there's nobody with Java skills in the team.

Comment: Ask a new question if you are stuck in  your image building!